# Sugar ORM and Android

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, sugarorm

After having followed the Documentation I have successfully added the jars and implemented the code of the example:

```
public class Book extends SugarRecord{
   String title;
   String edition;

   public Book(){

   }
   public Book(String title, String edition){
       this.title = title;
       this.edition = edition;
   }
}
```

And my Main Activity which is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
  Button btnAdd;
  EditText txtedition, txttitle;



  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
      btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);



      txtedition = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtedition);
      txttitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txttitle);

  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

      String edition = txtedition.getText().toString();
      String title = txttitle.getText().toString();
      switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.btnadd:
              Book book = new Book(title, edition);
              book.save();
              break;

      }
  }
}
```

My application builds successfully but when I'm pressing the add button I get the following exception:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                        Process: com.example.agds.demo, PID: 7939
>                                                                        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: BOOK (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO BOOK(TITLE,ID,EDITION) VALUES (?,?,?)
>                                                                        #################################################################
>                                                                        Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                                                                        Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>                                                                           (no such table: BOOK (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO BOOK(TITLE,ID,EDITION) VALUES (?,?,?))
>                                                                        #################################################################
>                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
>                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1058)
>                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:623)
>                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
>                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
>                                                                            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1607)
>                                                                            at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:266)
>                                                                            at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:360)
>                                                                            at com.example.agds.demo.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
>                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
>                                                                            at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10888)
>                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22541)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added those meta-data on your AndroidManifest inside your < application/>?

```
<meta-data android:name="DATABASE" android:value="sugar_example.db" />
<meta-data android:name="VERSION" android:value="2" />
<meta-data android:name="QUERY_LOG" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="DOMAIN_PACKAGE_NAME" android:value="com.example.yourmodels" />
```

Also, put this on your `<aplication>`

```
android:name="com.orm.SugarApp"
```

That is an Application class in the library.

https://github.com/chennaione/sugar/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/orm/SugarApp.java

or, if you already have your own Application class, you could extend it.

```
public class YourApp extends SugarApp {
}
```

Comment: Yes I already had declared all these in the Manifest when I mentioned this exception!

Comment: Actually when I removed all these from my Manifest it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Note that Sugar won't work (at least it won't create new tables) if you have Instant Run turned on in Android Studio.